# Making a div go over another when animating

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, overlay

I am making a portfolio page and have each item displayed with the image.

I want to make everything visible when the user hovers over the box. I have the hover part working, however it pushed the divs below it down. I would like it to go over the top of the other divs so i can give it a shadow. I have looked everywhere but the solutions do not work. Below is the relevant bit of code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainContent">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae sequi minima saepe amet placeat reiciendis! Quod, qui magnam animi labore accusantium veniam eveniet dicta maxime ipsum ducimus mollitia obcaecati modi!</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary project-btn">View Project</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae sequi minima saepe amet placeat reiciendis! Quod, qui magnam animi labore accusantium veniam eveniet dicta maxime ipsum ducimus mollitia obcaecati modi!</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary project-btn">View Project</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
 var pos = $(this).offset();
 $( this ).animate({
     height: "455px"
 }, 200);
 }, function() {
     $( this ).animate({
     height: "187px"
 }, 200);
```

});

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail {
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
```

}

Here is a jsfiddle of what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nS48w/2/

Comment: Have you tried modifying the z-index?

Comment: I did think of this but because there will be multiple rows it wouldn't really work because making row have a z index of 100 for example then row 2 have 50 row 2 wont overlay row 3 etc

Comment: The way I see it, that's an easily avoidable problem if you set all rows to have the same z-index and then only change one particular div's z-index on hover. Am I misinterpreting your concerns here?

Comment: After trying your idea it doesn't work it still pushed the divs below it.

Answer (score 1):

one solution (of many): absolutely position your thumbnails and set the z-index

see: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qNuY4/1/

```
.thumbnail {
    ....
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    ....
}

.top { top: 10px; z-index: 100;}

.bottom {top: 250px; z-index: 90; }
```

Comment: How would this work with multiple rows of 4. Also would this means i will have manually position each box because of the position absolute?